# How can I programming detect that a Bulb/LED is ON/OFF or a circuit is working as expected using Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I've created a circuit to turn on bulb using GSM module and Arduino. I want a mechanism(or programming) to know whether the bulb is on or off or fused. I've tried taking the input from the pins. But it only tells whether the pin is on or off but not the circuit as a whole.

Comment: You could measure current (perhaps as voltage across a small shunt resistor inline with the load).  Or you could use a photocell or other light detector.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a few methods.  The simplest and least expensive option is to measure the current consumption of the device you want to verify correct operation of, and see if it's using enough, but not too much, current.

For instance, the following would work well in the arduino case of using an LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ySWi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Connect the `Power` to 5V or to the pin you're controlling the LED with. Connect the `Sense` to an analog input such as A0.

If the LED isn't installed, or is broken as an open circuit, the sense would register 5V.  If the LED is broken as a shorted element, the sense would register 0v. If the LED is operating correctly, you would sense the voltage drop of the LED (which varies according to the LED's design), but it would be well above 0V and well below 5V.

For bulbs and other loads, use a much smaller resister for R1 (so the resistor doesn't affect the load as much) and it would be considered a current shunt.  Knowing the resister value, and the voltage at the `Sense` location will give you a current value using `Current = Voltage / Resistance`. Again, the load should be drawing current within an acceptable range during proper operation.  If it's not drawing enough current, or too much current, it may not be operating correctly.

This won't tell you if the LED is on, however it's a very reliable method to discover if it's working correctly, and you'll probably never run into a situation where the correct LED is installed and in the right current range, but not emitting light.

Comment: Yes, though putting the sense resistor on the ground side can let you measure with a lower reference on the ADC which helps if the resistor is small in value, and if it is protected with a diode clamp in case the load open-circuits can let you measure the current on loads supplied from a higher voltage than the ATmega.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Correct, but it also messes with shared grounds and can be confusing for electronics beginners. Consider, instead, trying to determine if a zigbee or bluetooth radio is operating correctly.  As it transmits its ground would be bouncing relative to the Arduino's ground, messing up communications.  I wouldn't recommend it to an arduino beginner generally, and specifically in this case where the voltage is known to be lower than the analog input, the circuit requires a resistor, and in the vast majority of beginner LED designs the resistor is always high side - not that it matters.